# Mobile Broadband, Wi-Fi stopped working

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, network-manager, usb-modem

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a new Acer VN7-792G and everything was working normally until about a week ago when the Mobile Broadband dongle and WiFi stopped working. When inserting the dongle, a prompt to run Huawei shows up, but it doesn't do anything. At first rebooting while the dongle is inserted seemed to solve the problem but later on it stopped working completely. After this trying to connect to Wifi became problematic as it crashes Network Manager and I will have to reboot just to get it working again (just the applet, connecting to Wifi is not possible at this moment).

Typing `lsusb` in terminal shows the dongle:

`Bus 001 Device 006: ID 12d1:1f01 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131 (Mass storage mode)`

I tried

`sudo service NetworkManager stop
sudo service NetworkManager start`

doesn't work.

I typed this and edited to add E3272, and changed it again to E353/E3131:

`sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules`

Didn't work. I typed:

`sudo systemctl restart modemmanager` and `sudo service modemmanager restart`, and for both I got this:

`Failed to restart modemmanager.service: Unit modemmanager.service not found.`

I tried: `sudo restart modemmanager`, then I got this:

`restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused`

Then I typed this:
`service modemmanager status`, for which I got the following:

`● modemmanager.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)`

After a little online research I suspect this occurred after an update, and caused some sort of clash between upstart and systemd process, but I'm not sure. I'm at the end of my rope and I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: I have a feeling that either Chili555 or Pilot6 will be able to help you with this.

Comment: Are they users on askubuntu?

Comment: Yes, they are..

Comment: Does `eject /dev/sr0` or `eject /dev/sr1` have any affect on the `lsusb` results

Comment: `eject /dev/sr0` ejects the bluray drive, and `eject /dev/sr1` gives the following result:
`eject: unable to find or open device for: '/dev/sr1'`, with no change.